# symfony Delete remember me cookie when logging out

Tags: php, symfony, cookies, remember-me

There is a `delete_cookies` in the security configuration file: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html

I have `remember_me` enabled. Everything works fine except when an user goes to the 'logout' link (directly from the url bar), I want symfony to delete the `REMEMBERME` cookie. How can I achieve that? Am I missing something?

When I go to url `/app/logout`, I can see the chrome dev tools that I still have the `REMEMBERME` cookie.

This is my **security.yml** file:

```
firewalls:     
    app_secured:
        anonymous: ~
        switch_user: true
        pattern: ^(/$|/login$|/app/)
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login_check
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            default_target_path: index
            always_use_default_target_path: true
        remember_me:
            key: "%secret%"
            lifetime: 2592000
            path: ~
            domain: ~
        logout:
            invalidate_session: true
            delete_cookies:
                REMEMBERME: { path: null, domain: null}
            path: logout
            target: login
access_control:
    - { path: ^/app/_sys/, roles: ROLE_NO_ACCESS }
    - { path: ^/app/, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/app/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

**Routing.yml**

```
login:
    path:      /
    defaults:  { _controller: AppWebBundle:Login:login }
login_check:
    path: /login_check
logout:
    path: /app/logout
```

**LoginController.php**

```
/**
 * Login controller.
 * @Route("/")
 */
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Login page
     * @Route("/login", name="login2")
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request){
        /** Reduced for simplicity, same code as: 
            http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#using-a-traditional-login-form **/
        return $this->render('AppWebBundle:Default:login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername,'error'=> $error,]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it doesn't work if you put directly the logout url into the url bar. The user has to click logout in order to work.

Creating a link `<a href="{{url('logout')}}">Logout</a>` and clicking it worked.

Comment: @JovanPerovic I know it doesn't but that did the trick. I guess it has something to do with how HTTP and Cache works? I don't really know. I hope someone could explain.

Comment: You sure you weren't just missing `app_dev.php`?

Comment: @Ryall Nope. Everything worked fine when clicking the logout url link instead of directly putting it into the browser url bar. Maybe it was a Chrome bug.

Comment: This fixed it for me too. I think the difference is, I was creating the href as /logout, where as what it actually needs to work is http://server.url/logout

Answer (score 5):

```
$response = new Response();
$response->headers->clearCookie('REMEMBERME');
$response->send();
```

You could delete the cookie with this in a controller

Comment: Correct, but prefer `$response->sendHeaders()`.

Answer (score 0):

Removing in server side the REMEMBERME token after logout should be automatic but it's not.
To do so, you'll have to change the way you store your token.

Since Symfony 2.8, the easy way is to use Doctrine to store tokens in database:

```
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    # ...

    firewalls:
        main:
            # ...
            remember_me:
                secret: '%kernel.secret%'
                # ...
                token_provider:
                    doctrine: true
```

Doing this will not only store token in database, it will invalidate it on logout event.

You can learn more in the documentation : https://symfony.com/doc/6.1/security/remember_me.html